# Prepared statement sql string suggestion required?

Tags: java, hibernate, prepared-statement

Hi i have a class which contains different methods for checking database values.
Each method is for a particular table, so the select sql remains the same each time the method is called only the where clause value to be checked changes ,so i am using prepared statement

like

```
public boolean checkVal(Session session,String b,String c,String d)
    {
        String sql="select a from tbl_name where b=? and c=? " +
                "and d=? ";
        Query query=session.createSQLQuery(sql).addScalar("a",Hibernate.STRING);
        query.setParameter(0,b);
        query.setParameter(1,c);
        query.setParameter(2,d);

    if(){
some check and return
}
}
```

this method is to be called like 100000 times, so i think the sql will get regenerated and using a prepared statement here is useless, so what should i do to increase performance? what should be the right approach for doing this?

Comment: How often old values change in those tables?

Comment: I thought of using a cache, but in this case, it's useless.

Comment: Maybe you're not thinking about your case properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SQL String can be static and final; there's no reason to recreate it each time.

But that's not your biggest problem.

`PreparedStatement` was born for binding and repeated execution.  There's nothing better.  The JDBC driver can cache the PreparedStatement once it's parsed and validated, so you only do that work once.

Have you measured performance and found a performance issue with this method?  If not, don't guess that you've got a problem until you have some data.

I'd ask why the method has to be called repeatedly.  Is it once each for 100,000 users?  If yes, there's nothing you can do except reduce your audience or eliminate the need for the call.  (Think caching.)  100,000 for a single user?  Figure out how to make one call or batch them.  You'll die a latent death with that arrangement.  Hyperbole on your part?  Take a deep breath, relax, and get some data.

Comment: actually it is kind of unique check, that before inserting value into the table i check first.. and the values generated are like 100000 per request, so this method is called a lot of time, so now if i declare the string as final , should i declare it locally or globally?

Comment: That's ridiculous.  You need to redesign this, pronto.  As for the the SQL String, I would make it a static final - a class constant.

Comment: ok so you mean to say that once the prepared statement is passed, it will use the one in the cache? and there will be no performance degrade?

Comment: No, I didn't say that.  If you execute a single PreparedStatement 100,000 times, each one with a network roundtrip, then you'll die a latent death regardless.  In that case, the PreparedStatement won't be the issue.  You should figure out how to reduce network latency.

Answer (score 1):

No, the `sql` variable is just a constant string expression, so it's not going to be created each time. There will be a single `String` object which is used each time it's called.

Even if this *did* create a new string each time, this would be incredibly unlikely to be a performance bottleneck. Have you measured the performance? Is it problematic? Do you have any reason to believe that the problem is due to this code rather than (say) a bottleneck in the database itself?

I would *hope* that Hibernate uses a `PreparedStatement` cache for this, but you should look into it.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a Hibernate named query, which would avoid the HQL or SQL parsing by Hibernate at each invocation (why use a SQL query instead of a HQL one here?).

In the end, Hibernate will ask the JDBC connection to create a prepared statement. And if your connection pool or driver caches prepared statement, there is a good chance that you get an already prepared statement if this method is used so often.